# How does one reference a view programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've created a layout. All done programmatically. Now I have a button that's set to change the VISIBILITY of a view when clicked. Frankly, I don't know how to reference the view.

Here's part of the code:

```
    //my button to show pop-up
    Button btn_showPop = new Button(this);
    btn_showPop.setText("Pop-up");
    btn_showPop.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btn_showPop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hsv.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (Menu_Displayed) {
                        //pop-up
                        li_pop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //how do I reference li_pop
                    } else {
                        //do nothing
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // pop-up:
    final LinearLayout li_pop = new LinearLayout(this);
    li_pop.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    li_pop.setOrientation(1);// 1 is vertical
    li_pop.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    li_pop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    li_pop.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "reference the view"? if you have given it a name, then isn't that a good enough reference?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but which thread is `hsv` posting to? If it's anything other than the ui thread then you are doing it wrong, you shouldn't interact with views outside the ui thread, in fact unless you want to do `hsv.postDelayed()`, just remove the hsv part because 1, you are creating an extra object (Runnable) and you can avoid it, and 2, it makes your code confusing if you are simply posting to the same thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as for getting reference to dynamically created View

first `decalre li_pop`  at class level

```
 LinearLayout li_pop;
```

second set id for `li_pop` at time of creation as :

```
li_pop = new LinearLayout(this);
li_pop.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

 li_pop.setId(599980); // set LinearLayout id here
```

now you can reference `li_pop`  LinearLayout as on button click :

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hsv.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (Menu_Displayed) {
                        //pop-up
                        li_pop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                      //OR
                 LinearLayout li_popnew=(LinearLayout)findViewById(599980);
                    li_popnew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    } else {
                        //do nothing
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks. I just removed "final" and it worked. Didn't use setID anymore.

Comment: @user1923613 : f9 but if you set id for both LinearLayout and Button then you can reference it in whole Activity and second way is just declare both at class level

Answer (score 0):

Move the line

```
final LinearLayout li_pop = new LinearLayout(this);
```

before the reference.

Comment: This wouldn't make any difference, the `OnClickListener` is created at runtime when the button is clicked, at this point the layout has already been created

Comment: @vikki thats not the problem. But the code as it is (with li_pop declared after the reference) does not compile.

Comment: i haven't tested that but even if it compiles, li_pop will go out of scope before `OnClickListener` is created because it's created in the function's scope, if you click the button the app will crash

Comment: No the app will not crash. Not the variable is used in the handler but its value (i.e. the pointer to the view). Try it, its perfectly OK.